# Is there a way to build an object through intersection?

Tags: modifiers

I am really stumped by this logo I am trying to animate, and I am not sure what to search for or how to phrase a search query. I have been trying to use the Boolean Modifier with this approach, but the problem is that the object I am trying to animate is gone after the mesh I am intersecting the object with moves away from the object.

**The setup that I have got so far:**

1. Start with a torus, and then add a sphere that is slightly big as
   the thickness of the torus.
2. Create a circular path such that the path roughly goes through the
   center of a circle made from a cross-section of the torus.
   (Basically, the path is inside and centered around the torus).
3. Constrain the sphere to follow the circular path. Now I have a
   sphere that goes around a torus.

[image: sphere and torus]

**Now I want to do this:**

- As the circular sphere goes around the torus, the intersection of the
  sphere and the torus is revealed.
  [image: sphere torus intersection with Boolean modifier]
- As the sphere moves away from the newly revealed part, it stays there
  and does not disappear.
  [image: disappearing torus]

  *A nice bonus is if there is a way to add a glow to the object only when it
  is inside the sphere.*

Comment: There is alot of information to ask users to visualize...please [add images](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/206633/edit) to your question.

Comment: @Timaroberts Thanks! Added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to do it would be to array the boolean sphere with a rotating empty (or along a curve if your final shape is something else than a torus):

[image]

Create your torus, in *Object* mode create a sphere at the torus center, switch to *Edit* mode, move the sphere so that it contains a torus segment, the sphere origin must stay at the center of the torus:

[image]

Back to *Object* mode, create an empty at the same location:

[image]

Give your sphere an *Array* modifier, disable *Constant Offset*, enable *Object Offset* and choose the empty as *Object*, choose a *Count* around 20, but the amount will actually depend on the sphere size compared to the torus size:

[image]

At frame 0 of your *Timeline* keyframe the empty, at frame X rotate it as much as necessary on the Z axis so that all the sphere iterations cover the whole torus, keyframe again when you're good:

[image]

Give your torus a Boolean modifier with the sphere as *Object*. For the torus *Boolean*, choose *Exact* instead of *Fast*, and enable the *Self* option to make it work properly. It works fine in 2.9, you won't have the same options in the previous versions so I'm not sure this method will work properly. If your boolean is buggy, try another method like the sphere arrayed along a curve instead of a boolean:

[image]

Comment: if you downvote my answer please at least give an explanation: have I misunderstood the question? is my answer unclear? etc... thanks    ;)

Comment: this is exactly what I am looking for. Could you provide a little bit more detail on how to do this.

Comment: sure, i'm going to edit

Answer (score 2):

You almost have it.  In your last photo if you select the sphere and press Ctrl + A and apply its position, it'll move the object origin back to the center.

[image]

[image]

Then you can just rotate it around the Z axis.

[image]

Whatever material properties you set for the torus will only be shown for the visible portion, including volumes.

[image]

Comment: Oh, you know what.  I misunderstood this question.  My bad.

Comment: Perhaps with enough subdivisions a build modifier does what you want.  I'll leave this here as maybe it's still helpful.

Comment: This is cool and I didn't know this. Unfortunately, this is not what I am looking for. I guess my question is poorly worded. I am trying to use the sphere to draw the torus. In Blender 2d, you can draw with a pencil and use the Build modifier to seem like it is drawing on screen. I am trying to do something similar except drawing a mesh using another mesh. I am guessing that the Boolean modifier is not the way to do this, but I am not sure what would be close to doing this.

Comment: No I just missed one important bit of text.  You want the revealed part to remain.